# Python не распознаёт десятичные числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

Надо выполнить простейшую вычислительную операцию:

```
print('0.5 + 0.3 =', int(0.5+0.3))
```

Но Python не распознаёт эти числа и выводит

```
0.5 + 0.3 = 0
```

Если одно из этих чисел заменяется на целое, выводится результат, на который повлияло только целое число:

```
print('5 + 0.3 =', int(5+0.3))
```

```
5 + 0.3 = 5
```

Что делать?

Comment: А ты просто int'ануть 0.8 пробовал? Он int(0.8) выдает как 0, однако... Вот и твой ответ. Да и вообще, зачем ты делаешь int?

Comment: Привет! А зачем вы применяете функцию округления до целого `int()`. Может быть вы хотели сказать `print('0.5 + 0.3 =', 0.5+0.3)`

Comment: int приведение числа к целому, ты просто берешь и отбрасываешь дробную часть, кончено же у  тебя будет 0

Comment: Перефразирую вопрос: я сказал отбрасывать дробную часть и мой код теперь отбрасывает дробную часть. Что делать?

Comment: int на str поменяй...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>>print('0.5 + 0.3 =', int(0.5+0.3))
0.5 + 0.3 = 0
>>>print('0.5 + 0.3 =', str(0.5+0.3))
0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8
```

Так?

Comment: а зачем там вообще str?

Comment: Можно и без, да. Просто привычка что если начинаю работать со строкой, то и дальше все в строки делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Просто поменяй `int()` на `float()`. 
Мне помогло.